# Silverlight: discover and invoke webservice dynamically

Tags: silverlight, web-services, call, dynamic

I have a Silverlight application and I would need to be able to get data from practically any webservice. I'd like to provide the functionality for the user to specify an URL of a webservice during runtime, then my app would discover the service and offer some UI to select the webmethod and fill the necessary parameters. Then the user could call the webservice and the app would display the data on the UI.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What are you going to do with random data?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean a SOAP web service? There are many components in .NET that you would normally want to use for this (e.g. WCF's metadata download and client proxy generation functionality, based on CodeDOM, as well as various classes for dealing with WSDL and XSD schema). Unfortunately, these are not present in Silverlight. So, I can think of two approaches:

1) Manually implement a general-purpose SOAP client in Silverlight (i.e. manually implement metadata download, WSDL parsing, XSD parsing, etc) - this will be very difficult unless you can find some existing code for this that you can adapt to Silverlight (and even then it's probably still very difficult)

2) Do it through the server. The server will do all the difficult parts, and Silverlight will just display the UI. Still not an easy task, but possible; You can start by reverse-engineering how the WCF Test Client application works by using Reflector and go from there.